# Conditional Formatting Sheet API

Tags: api, http, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I´d like to change a **whole row color** depending on the value of a row´s field:

POST
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/19D_Ctr5pzfuwfT2XlFDIEVsQv2ezMyShwCm-AAq7KY0:batchUpdate

BODY:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "addConditionalFormatRule": {
        "rule": {
          "ranges": [
            {
              "sheetId": 0
            }
          ],
          "booleanRule": {
            "condition": {
              "type": "TEXT_EQ",
              "values": [
                {
                  "userEnteredValue": "ERROR"
                }
              ]
            },
            "format": {
              "backgroundColor": {
                "green": 0.2,
                "red": 0.8
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "index": 0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

With this request, I´m changing the cell, but not thew whole row.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This Works:

```
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "addConditionalFormatRule": {
                "rule": {
                    "ranges": [
                        {
                            "sheetId": 0,
                            "startRowIndex": 0
                        }
                    ],
                    "booleanRule": {
                        "condition": {
                            "type": "CUSTOM_FORMULA",
                            "values": [
                                {
                                    "userEnteredValue": "=$D1=\"ERROR\""
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "format": {
                            "backgroundColor": {
                                "green": 0.2,
                                "red": 0.8
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "index": 0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).